# PrimeFaces 4.0 PF is not defined

Tags: jsp, primefaces, progress-bar

I am trying to implement progress bar using PrimeFaces 4.0.

I have followed the example on the official website:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf

However, after I have copied and pasted the codes and run it,

firebug has told me that

> "PF is not defined."

Please find my code below:

```
<h:form>

            <p:growl id="growl" />

            <h3>Client Side ProgressBar</h3>
            <p:commandButton value="Start" id="start" type="button"
                onclick="start()" widgetVar="startButton1" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancel" type="button"
                onclick="cancel()" />

            <p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" widgetVar="pbClient"
                style="width:300px" />

        </h:form>
```

And below is my javascripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    PF('startButton1').disable();

    window['progress'] = setInterval(function() {
        var pbClient = PF('pbClient'),
        oldValue = pbClient.getValue(),
        newValue = oldValue + 10;

        pbClient.setValue(pbClient.getValue() + 10);

        if(newValue === 100) {
            clearInterval(window['progress']);
        }


    }, 1000);
}

function cancel() {
    clearInterval(window['progress']);
    PF('pbClient').setValue(0);
    PF('startButton1').enable();
}
```

Which basically are copied from the official website example.

Comment: do you have <h:head/> in your xhtml?

Comment: This should be the format of you xhtml `<html>
    <h:head>
      //code
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        //code
    </h:body>
</html>`

Comment: I have used <h:head> and <h:body> tags, but no luck,
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Title</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="growl" />
                <h3>Client Side ProgressBar</h3>
                <p:commandButton value="Start" id="start" type="button"
                                 onclick="start()" widgetVar="startButton1" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancel" type="button"
                                 onclick="cancel()" />
                <p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" widgetVar="pbClient"
                               style="width:300px" />
            </h:form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function start() {
                    PF('startButton1').disable();

                    window['progress'] = setInterval(function() {
                        var pbClient = PF('pbClient'),
                                oldValue = pbClient.getValue(),
                                newValue = oldValue + 10;

                        pbClient.setValue(pbClient.getValue() + 10);

                        if (newValue === 100) {
                            clearInterval(window['progress']);
                        }


                    }, 1000);
                }

                function cancel() {
                    clearInterval(window['progress']);
                    PF('pbClient').setValue(0);
                    PF('startButton1').enable();
                }
            </script>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Camargo,
the format of my page is the same as the one you suggested,
but still no luck for me.
Firebug does not report the PF is not defined error,
but the progress bar and command buttons are not showing.